# Both asterisk and ampersand in a parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, memory-address

I am reading a book about Binary Search Tree and something weird came up. I came across the following declaration in a function parameter.

```
BinaryNode * & t
```

What does it mean? Pointer of the address of `t`?

---

For context, this is the code where I saw this. The private `insert` function is a helper function for public `insert` function, and private `insert` function looks for the right place to insert using recursion.

```
class BST
{
public:
   void insert(const Comparable & item)

private:
   BinaryNode *root;
   struct BinaryNode
   {
       Comparable element;
       BinaryNode *left;
       BinaryNode *right;
       BinaryNode(const Comparable & theElement, BinaryNode *lt, BinaryNode *rt) : 
          element(theElement), left(lt), right(rt) {}
   }
   void insert(const Comparable & item, BinaryNode * & t) const;
};
```

Comment: Think about what each does separately when used in a function parameter and then combine them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your expression `BinaryNode * & t)`

```
            BinaryNode*                & t
           -------------              -----
            BinaryNode pointer        t is reference variable
```

so `t` is reference to pointer of *BinaryNode* class.

> Pointer of the address of t?

You are confused `ampersand &` operator  in c++. that give address of an variable. but syntax is different.

`ampersand &` in front of some of variable like below:

```
BinaryNode b;
BinaryNode* ptr = &b;
```

But following way is for reference variable (its simple not pointer):

```
BinaryNode b;
BinaryNode & t  = b;
```

and your is like below:

```
BinaryNode b;
BinaryNode* ptr = &b;
BinaryNode* &t  = ptr;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a reference to pointer. You can change pointer in this function and it will be changed outside.