# C++ to C difference & *

Tags: c++, c, pointers, ampersand

I've a C++ program like this:

```
typedef struct _nodo
{
    ...
} node;    

void cuenta(node& *Lista, char c);
```

When I compile don`t show any error.
Now, when I want to use this code for a C program, the compiler show error:

```
error: expected ')'
void cuenta(node* &Lista, char c);
```

What its the difference between `&` and `*` in C++ and C?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this question has not been asked before.  Succinctly, the `&` in the argument list is a C++ feature (references) that is simply not present in C.  What you show is valid C++ but invalid C.  You'd have to use a `*` in place of the `&` and adjust the syntax to all uses of the parameter in the body of the function, and make sure you call the function with `&var` in place of just `var`.  So, C++ is syntactically more convenient.

Comment: Read: [both asterisk and ampersand in a parameter c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314640/both-asterisk-and-ampersand-in-a-parameter-c/14314703#14314703)

Comment: These questions are different. This one is specifically asking if there's a difference in C and C++ implementation. The other is asking the purpose of *& in C++. I would not say they are duplicate.

Comment: I actually came to this question from the one marked duplicate, and the question or the solutions there did not tell me that C does it differently, so a person would not necessarily be aware of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`node& *Lista` would be a pointer to a reference to some `node` in C++ (but that is not possible in C++), but reference types don't exist in C, so it is invalid syntax in C. BTW, you probably meant `node* &Lista` -a reference to a pointer- ...

So in C you'll pass a pointer to a pointer, and e.g. declare your parameter `node**pLista` and use everywhere inside your function `*pLista` instead of the `Lista` reference of C++.

Comment: You can't have a pointer to a reference anyway ([as shown](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8918369fcf7f01b2)). It was probably meant to be a reference to a pointer.