# What's the meaning of *& used together

Tags: c++

```
class parent
{ 
    protected:
        int a;
};

class child : public parent
{
    public:
    void addOne(parent * &);
};

void child::addOne(parent * &parentClass)
{
     a=5;
    }

int main()
{
    parent a;
    child b;
    parent* ap = &a;
    b.addOne(ap);
}
```

In above example *** and &** sing  both are used in a function parameter like `*&`, can any body explain what does it mean is it reference or pointer?

Comment: [both asterisk and ampersand in a parameter c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314640/both-asterisk-and-ampersand-in-a-parameter-c/14314703#14314703)

Answer (score 3):

It's a reference to a pointer.

Behind the scenes the compiler will pass the address of the pointer.

Though your example doesn't show it, references are typically used to

- change the passed parameter (in this case, the pointer).
- to save a needless copy of an object (when const reference is used).

Answer (score 3):

When you need to modify the *pointer*, not just the data pointed to by it, you should pass a *reference to a pointer*. Just like any other variable.

Answer (score 1):

It means a reference to a pointer variable.

You can pass a variable of a pointer type, and the method can the variable's value. Which means you can change what the original pointer is pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

it is called `ref-to-pointer`. 
It is similar to ptr-to-ptr, but there are some differents just like ref vs ptr in c++ language.